# How can I prepend a default value to all echo calls in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell, echo

I have a bash script containing multiple `echo` calls:

```
 #!bin/bash
 echo 'a'
 echo 'b'
 echo 'c'
```

I want to prepend a default text to all of these echo calls to get an output like this:

```
default_text: a
default_text: b
default_text: c
```

Is there a way to do this globally inside the script without adding the default text to each one of the echo calls?

**Note:** Below there are 2 very good answers to this question. The one accepted resolves the problem specifically for `echo` commands. The second one resolves the problem globally inside the script for *any* command that outputs to stdout.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Define a function:

```
function echo {
    builtin echo 'default_text: ' "$@" ;
}
```

The `builtin` is needed, otherwise the function would be recursive.

Answer (score 4):

This bash technique will work for *any* command that emits text to stdout:

```
exec 1> >(sed 's/^/default text: /')
```

```
$ echo foo
default text: foo
$ date
default text: Wed Jul 24 07:43:38 EDT 2013
$ ls
default text: file1
default text: file2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
alias echo="echo 'default_text: '"
```

Comment: By default, aliases are not expanded in noninteractive shells.